# 'Select' form element breaks my site's responsive layout

Tags: html, css, forms, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my site mobile-friendly using a responsive layout, but the SELECT controls in forms break it, exceeding beyond screen width wherever they contain a long OPTION item.

What is the correct way to deal with those form elements?

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Sometimes select boxes with long explanations make ugly view to desktop designs either. Try not to use long explanations in select options. you can put explanations in other boxes per option select.

Comment: I guess you could use Javascript that detects the smaller width, and goes through all the `<option>` elements, truncates the text, and adds ellipsis.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu no I'm not using any framework, just plain'ol html/css ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max-width` to limit the size of your `<select>`. It is generally good idea to give your selects `max-width: 100%; text-overflow: ellipsis;`

Max-width will limit size of  to its parent's width and if an option overflows, than its text will be truncated with neat ellipsis in nice browsers and simply cut in the middle in other ones.

After clicking the select, option list appears. The list can be wider in standard desktop browser, but it's size doesn't count into body size, so it won't mangle your layout. On mobile, that probably won't be problem since mobile browsers display option lists differently.

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLLvVV